# Paypal integration options and applications

Tags: paypal

I have never worked with paypal before and am finding the multitude of account types and labyrinthine documentation spread over multiple websites very difficult to navigate. Below is what I am trying to do, maybe someone could steer me in the right direction.

I am building a website which sells customers access to certain content on the site. New content is frequently added. Customers do not need a shopping cart, they will only check out for a single item at a time. I am fine with sending the customers off my site to paypal for checkout, but I need to include parameters (user id,product Id, security token etc) that will be returned to my applications with successful checkout, so that the my website can automatically grant the user access to whatever content they just paid for. Also they should automatically be returned to my site after the payment is finished.

What is the easiest way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your requirements - all you need is the PayPal Standard product: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant. Using that you can create simple HTML buttons that you can host on your site to collect payments.

If you can interested in finding more about APIs and other solutions you can refer to my blog post here: https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/praveen/paypal-apis-galaxy-not-so-far-away

Comment: Would the buttons be able to be created dynamically on my site though? Or must I create one on paypal each time I create a new item on my site?

Comment: there is a Button manager API: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/button-manager

Answer (score 0):

Paypal is great but check this out 
https://gumroad.com/

It might be easier than Paypal in your condition.